# Mongoose: Calculate the number of grouped documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mern

I have this mongoose query:

```
const filter_stage = {
  $match: {
    category: "LOGIN",
  },
};
const active_users_group_stage = {
  $group: {
    _id: "$user",
    number_of_logins: { $sum: 1 },
  },
};

const pipeline = [filter_stage, active_users_group_stage];

const active_users_stats = await History.aggregate(pipeline);
response.active_users_stats = active_users_stats;
const number_of_active_users = active_users_stats.length;
```

This is the `History` model:

```
const HistorySchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users",
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["LOGIN","LOGOUT"],
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

And it returns something like this:

```
[
        {
            "_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "number_of_logins": 45
        },
        {
            "_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "number_of_logins": 36
        },
        {
            "_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "number_of_logins": 26
        },
        {
            "_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "number_of_logins": 18
        },
        {
            "_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "number_of_logins": 18
        },
]
```

Instead of calculating the number of active users like this:

```
const number_of_active_users = active_users_stats.length;
```

I would like to calculate it inside the aggregate pipeline.
Is this possible?

Comment: Is this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GLUzrfumQ7u) meets your requirement?

Comment: Yes, that works in the example I provided earlier but I realized what I am working on is a bit more complicated and I just updated the code.

Comment: Hmmm, I think would be the same. Add the `$group` stage (I posted in demo link) as the last stage. Then In your Node.JS, `response.active_users_stats = active_users_stats[0].users;` and `const number_of_active_users = active_users_stats[0].number_of_active_users;`

Answer (score 0):

You need `$group` all with `_id: null` to sum all `active_users` and add all documents into the `users` array as the last stage.

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: null,
    number_of_active_users: {
      $sum: 1
    },
    users: {
      $push: "$$ROOT"
    }
  }
}
```

As the `active_users_stats` result will return an array with only one document,

```js
...

const all_group_stage = {
  $group: {
    _id: null,
    number_of_active_users: {
      $sum: 1
    },
    users: {
      $push: "$$ROOT"
    }
  },
};

const pipeline = [filter_stage, active_users_group_stage, all_group_stage];

const active_users_stats = await History.aggregate(pipeline);
response.active_users_stats = active_users_stats[0].users;
const number_of_active_users = active_users_stats[0].number_of_active_users;
```

Comment: Actually, that would return the number of logins of all users. So for example, if a user has logged in 3 times, he will be counted 3 times in number_of_active_users.

Comment: So based on your provided result, you want `number_of_active_users` as: 45 + 36 +26 + 18 + 18 = 143? A bit confuse that with `.length()` as beginning, you will get 5 which is size of array. Would be great if you can improve the question, specifying the requirement.

Comment: It will return the number of documents in the users array - exactly what you get with `active_users_stats.length;` in the question.  It would worth mentioning that pushing all documents into an array of a single document can exhaust the 16MB limit on the larger datasets.

Comment: @YongShun Exactly, the result should be 5. In other words, 5 users logged in. In the code your provided it returns the sum of the number of logins of all users. Here is an example, If two users logged in 5 and 22 times, respectively, I need the result to be 2 and not 27.

Comment: Nope, with the sample demo link shared in the comment, it returns the size of `users` for `number_of_active_users`. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example for the incorrect scenario you mentioned.